# Stereo Balance in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I have a headset that I use on Windows 10 and is just fine, but when on my linux installation you can hardly hear anything from the left ear. How should I balance the audio?

I am using Arch Linux with KDE Plasma 5.

I have built my own pc and its specs are:
AMD Ryzen 2700X CPU
Sapphire RX 580 nitro+ GPU
2 * 8GB Gskill Ripjaws V 3200 Mhz RAM
ASUS ROG B450-F Motherboard

When I run `lspci -v | grep audio` nothing shows up. Is this bad?

Comment: Please, provide more information about your system. e.g. your desktop environment

Comment: 1) Which brand of PC? 2) What's the model part number from the serial number sticker? 3) Please run _sudo lspci -v | grep audio_  then highlight the resulting text, copy it, then return here. Please click [edit] and add the answers for items 1-3 into your question so we can help

Comment: to add one more needful specification onto the wise questions of mattia.b89 and K7AAY:  there are (at least) potentially two layers to the sound stack, "alsa" or pulseaudio (which is atop alsa).  Arch uses systemd out of the box, so pulseaudio is likely but not assured.  One can therefore ask if pavucontrol as  utility is installed, and if so, activate that and you'll see left/right channels which can be independently controlled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after installing `pulseaudio-alsa` and `pavucontrol` the problem fixed itself.